# D3 DateTime parser takes into account timezone

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, d3.js, timezone

I have this URL and I need to parse and convert the `mydate` timestamp into a UTC datetime (in Javascript).

```
http://www.blablabla.com/#mydate=2009-10-12T22:09:28.000
```

Obviously the date encoded in the URL is just string so it doesn't convey any timezone information: however it is meant to represent a UTC time.

Converting a UTC timestamp string into a UTC Datetime seems to be quite straightforward however I get this problem:

I'm using D3 time parser to do it, here the important bit:

```
var iso = d3.time.format.utc("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%L");
var dateObj = iso.parse(mydate);
```

The `mydate` is a string and it's just a clipped version of the URL containing the timestamp bit:

```
2009-10-12T22:09:28.000
```

The output of the `.parse` function is:

```
 Mon Oct 12 2009 23:09:28 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)
```

I'd have expected this (this is what I want):

```
Mon Oct 12 2009 22:09:28
```

The OS and the browser are set to UTC time (here we are currently in GMT). 
So why I get the (GMT Daylight Time) part instead of a plain UTC string?

**EDIT**

Even with a simple `new Date(2009, 9, 12, 22, 09, 28)` I get the same issue (no D3, no MomentJS, just a plain JavaScript DateTime object)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value "GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)" is Windows's funny way of saying "British Summer Time" (or, BST).  [In 2009, BST ran from March 29 to October 25](http://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/uk/london?year=2009), thus your date of October 12 is in that range.

Your time zone is not set to `"(UTC) Coordinated Universal Time"`, it's set for `"(UTC) Dublin, Edinburgh, Lisbon, London"`.   The value in parenthesis represents the *standard* offset only.  It doesn't reflect daylight saving time.

Lastly, the output is actually a `Date` object, not a string.  The JavaScript `Date` object presents most of its output in terms of *local time*, based on the time zone of the computer where it is running.  If you want the UTC time, then you can use `.toISOString()` instead of `.toString()`, though that will be in [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) extended format, rather than a human-readable format.

If you want a human-readable UTC-based format, since you're using D3 already, then do something like the following:

```
var iso = d3.time.format.utc("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%L");
var dateObj = iso.parse(mydate);

var fmt = d3.time.format.utc("%c"); // or whatever format you wish
var str = fmt.format(dateObj);
```

Refer to [D3's time formatting documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Formatting) for more details.